# Increase thickness of vistime y axis

Tags: r

How to increase the Y-axis and thickness of the bar. I want to make it look big. Rather than being narrow

```
data <- read.csv(text="event,group,start,end,color
                            Phase 1,Project,2016-12-22,2016-12-23,#c8e6c9
                            Phase 2,Project,2016-12-23,2016-12-29,#a5d6a7
                            Phase 3,Project,2016-12-29,2017-01-06,#fb8c00
                            Phase 4,Project,2017-02-06,2017-03-02,#DD4B39
                            Room 334,Team 1,2016-12-22,2016-12-28,#DEEBF7
                            Room 335,Team 1,2016-12-28,2017-01-05,#C6DBEF
                            Room 335,Team 1,2017-01-05,2017-01-23,#9ECAE1
                            Group 1,Team 2,2016-12-22,2016-12-28,#E5F5E0
                            Group 2,Team 2,2016-12-28,2017-01-23,#C7E9C0
                            3-200,category 1,2016-12-25,2016-12-25,#1565c0
                            3-330,category 1,2016-12-25,2016-12-25,#1565c0
                            3-223,category 1,2016-12-28,2016-12-28,#1565c0
                            3-225,category 1,2016-12-28,2016-12-28,#1565c0
                            3-226,category 1,2016-12-28,2016-12-28,#1565c0
                            3-226,category 1,2017-01-19,2017-01-19,#1565c0
                            3-330,category 1,2017-01-19,2017-01-19,#1565c0
                            1-217.0,category 2,2016-12-27,2016-12-27,#90caf9
                            4-399.7,moon rising,2017-01-13,2017-01-13,#f44336
                            8-831.0,sundowner drink,2017-01-17,2017-01-17,#8d6e63
                            9-984.1,birthday party,2016-12-22,2016-12-22,#90a4ae
                            F01.9,Meetings,2016-12-26,2016-12-26,#e8a735
                            Z71,Meetings,2017-01-12,2017-01-12,#e8a735
                            B95.7,Meetings,2017-01-15,2017-01-15,#e8a735
                        T82.7,Meetings,2017-01-15,2017-01-15,#e8a735")
    gg_vistime(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`gg_vistime` can be used as a `ggplot` object. This means you can change the `theme` like this:

```
library(vistime)
gg_vistime(data) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = "black", size = 2))
```

Output:

[image]

Check this [link](https://rpubs.com/mclaire19/ggplot2-custom-themes) for more information about creating custom themes in ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the `linewidth` argument to set your bar widths. Note that the value you set depends on the final size of your plot so you may need to play around to get an optimal value.

```
gg_vistime(data, linewidth=20)
```

[image: Vistime plot thicker bars]

### Update:

---

You say you "don't want the data to overlap". I assume you mean the `geom_points` used for events that have the same start and end time (as these are the only elements I can see that overlap). Looking at the underlying code for the [gg_vistime](https://github.com/shosaco/vistime/blob/master/R/plot_ggplot.R) function, it appears that the point size is set to be the `linewidth * 0.7`.

If you want to set the point size independent of the bar linewidths, you can override the aesthetic parameters for `geom_point` in the returned ggplot object. For example...

```
gg <- gg_vistime(data, linewidth=20)
gg$layers[[3]]$aes_params$size = 10
```

[image: gg_vistime point size edit]

Comment: But I don't want the data to overlap

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? Do you mean the labels? Or are you talking about the bars themselves? If the data is overlapping how do you want it to be displayed?